# What is the best way to get Dependency Property of Type in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, reflection, dependency-properties

I want to get `DependencyProperty` information by passing property name using reflection. I refereed many forums which guides to use `GetField` method.

```
DependencyProperty dp = null;
var fieldInfo = dependencyObjectType.GetField(dpName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
if (fieldInfo != null)
{
   dp = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as DependencyProperty;
}
```

this may not applicable for all control types. For example if you take, CheckBox type, Fields are empty.So what is the right way to get DependencyProperty details in silverlight?
My objective is, I am trying to bind controls using reflection. I want to achieve the following

```
Type controlType = Type.GetType("ControlName");
DependencyProperty dp = ?
FrameworkElement element = controlType as FramworkElement;
element.SetBinding(dp, new Binding("PropertyPath"));
```

Comment: Which DependencyProperty field exactly can't be retrieved from type CheckBox?

Comment: Works for me in Silverlight 4 and 5.